# Mobile Safari select all text in input

Tags: jquery, ios, select, input, mobile-safari

Somewhere in iOS 6 or 7, according to other SO threads, jquery's select() stopped working in Safari and people started recommending the native:

```
$('input')[0].setSelectionRange(0, 999);
```

As of writing (iOS 8.1.2), setSelectionRange() doesn't work either. See [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/h8jpa3dt/1/).

Is it possible to select all text an input in mobile safari?